# How do I shrink cell output?

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Jupyter notebook, if your output is too long, you can click beside the cell and shrink it to a smaller scrollable window. Is there a way to do something similar in google colab?

So the below picture which I had to cut off because the output is too long...

[image: long format]

Turns into this! A shorter scrollable window

[image: short format]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Javascript API `google.colab.output.setIframeHeight`. For example:

```
# Create a large DataFrame with random data.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

from IPython import display

# Display the DataFrame
display.display(df)

# Adjust the output height to 300px.
display.Javascript("google.colab.output.setIframeHeight('300px');")
```

Here's a complete notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PpqNj3aNYF1mQ9-AZvbqkUEFsADATuJR

Comment: Have a way to persist the size so you don't have to retype the last line code in all the cells you need?